# how to use variable in input function python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and trying to create a program to calculate grade. I've been stuck on below for over an hour now so any help appreciate.

```
assessment=[]    
weight=[]    
assign_number = int(input('How many assessment : '))    
for i in range(assign_number):    
   asses_name =input('Enter name of assessment: ')     
   assessment.append(asses_name)   
   asses_value = int(input(print('How many marks is the',assessment[i],'worth : ')))   
   weight.append(asses_value)
```

the problem is the asses_value keep returning none?example is below

How many assessment : 3
Enter name of assessment: test
How many marks is the test worth :
None

Any hint is appreciated, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print()` function in Python always returns None. So you need to remove it from this line:

```
asses_value = int(input(print('How many marks is the',assessment[i],'worth : ')))
```

Simply passing a string to the `input` function does what you need:

```
asses_value = int(input('How many marks is the ' + assessment[i] + ' worth : '))
```

Note that you can only pass a single string to `input()` though, which is why I have used the string concatenation operator `+` rather than passing three comma-separated strings.

As pointed out in the comments, an improvement to the above would be to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
asses_value = int(input('How many marks is the {} worth : '.format(assessment[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope! This code will help you out

```
assessment=[]    
weight=[]    
assign_number = int(input('How many assessment : '))    
for i in range(assign_number):    
   asses_name =input('Enter name of assessment: ')     
   assessment.append(asses_name)   
   asses_value = int(input('How many marks is the ' +assessment[i]+' worth : '))
   weight.append(asses_value)
```

**Update**:
You tried to print the the value while taking the input that's why all the error occur